# Print a variable column using awk

Tags: logging, awk

I'm trying to filter some mail logs and I need to get some specific information from certain columns that are not always the same. The information can be on different columns each line. I always use awk to print only the columns I want, like:

```
cat file.log | awk '{print $1" "$2" "$3}' >> output.txt
```

but in this case, I don't know which column contains the string I'm looking for.

Example file.log where I'm looking for columns that contain the string "5":

```
A B C 222 586 999 724 644  
A B C 510 333 987 678 633  
A B C 348 488 920 566 240
```

Result I want:

```
A B C 586  
A B C 510  
A B C 566
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: if at all you can consider `perl` then you can do `$perl -pe "s/^(\D+).*\b(5\d*).*/$1$2/" your_file.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) `~ /5/` and iterating on each columns on each rows/lines ([KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)) :

```
$ awk '
    {
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
            if (i==1 || i==2 || i==3 || $i ~ /5/) {
                printf "%s ", $i
            }
         }
         print ""
    }
' file
```

### Output:

```
A B C 586 
A B C 510 
A B C 566
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '{
    for(i=4;i<=NF;i++)    # iterate fields starting from the 4th
        if($i~/5/)        # if there is a 5 in the field
            $3=$3 OFS $i  # append field value to the 3rd field
    print $1,$2,$3        # output 1st thru 3rd
}' file

Output:

A B C 586
A B C 510
A B C 566
```

Comment: perhaps `OFS` instead of `" "`?

Answer (score 1):

a tricky perl one-liner

```
perl -anE 'say "@{[ @F[0..2], grep {/5/} @F[3..$#F] ]}"' file
```

where

- `-n` iterates over the input file by line
- `-a` splits each line into words, and stores into the `@F` array
- `@F[0..2]` is the first 3 words; `@F[3..$#F]` is the list of the 4th up to the last word
- `grep {/5/}` filters the list, returning only the words containing a "5"
- `"@{[ ... ]}"` is a syntax trick to stringify a list as space-separated.

Can also use this, just as tricky but a little less "syntax-y"

```
perl -anE 'push @F, grep {/5/} splice @F,3; say "@F"'
```

Comment: I guess `perl -pe "s/^(\D+).*\b(5\d*).*/$1$2/"` will do the job

Comment: `perl -ape "s/\d.*//s;$_=$_. join(' ', grep{/5/} @F).\"\n\"" file`